# Trouble installing Django

Tags: python, django, installation

I'm having trouble installing Django, even if I follow the instructions here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02/

Could someone please provide baby steps to installing Django. I'm talking baby steps that really break it down, so that a retarded person could do it.

I've installed Django and unzipped the file, but I'm unsure where to go from there.

I on Windows 7, and I've downloaded Python 2.7 and Django 1.2.1.

Comment: What versions of Python and Django do you have, also - is it Windows or Linux?

Comment: +1 to what cji said. Providing OS, Python and Django version information will get you better answers. Also add details about what you tried and what error(s) you got.

Comment: Windows 7, Python 2.7 and Django 1.2.1.

I'm not getting any errors, I just don't really know what to do after I've unzipped the Django file.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs#installing-an-official-release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. If you have Python installed, you can then proceed to execute `setup.py` given with Django. Head over to the directory where you unzipped Django.

```
cd C:\path\to\Django\
```

You can now execute

```
python setup.py install
```

This step requires your `python` executable to be present in the system's `PATH` environment variable. If it isn't you will have to [append your Python installation directory](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) to your `PATH`.

**Update**

You can verify that the installation has gone well with the following command. Run `python` and execute the command `import django`. If no import errors are thrown everything is OK. Thanks to [cji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280995/cji) for the tip.

Comment: You were faster :) I would mention the way to validate instalation: run python.exe and try `import django`.

Comment: something's not working. Do I type python setup.py install into the command prompt or IDLE? Also, where should I put the Django folder? Within the python folder? Do I add's the django directory to the PATH environment variable? I'm confused. What's the python executable?

Comment: @Justin in the command prompt. Everything else is irrelevant - `setup.py` will copy Django files to where they should be automatically, no matter where they were. 'python executable' is simply `python.exe` (on Windows).

Comment: @Justin: (1) You should type `python setup.py install` into the _command prompt_. You are executing **python.exe** with two arguments here. (2) There is no requirement on where the Django folder should be. In fact you can safely delete it _after_ you install Django. (3) you **do not** have to add Django directory to the PATH variable, only the Python installation directory (if you haven't already done so) (4) Python executable is the **python.exe** file that is present in the Python installation directory.

Comment: So I type python setup.py install into the command prompt and I get a SyntaxError. I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax with a "^" pointing to the "p" in "setup".

Comment: And when I type import django I get an error saying that the module doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Justin: Looks like you may have got Python REPL and windows command line mixed up. (1) Did you type `python setup.py install` and `import django` into the _same_ shell/command line? if you **did**, then it is a mistake (2) Can you post a screenshot of whatever you are trying?

Comment: I'm having trouble posting a screenshot to SO. Could you send me your email so I could mail it to you?

Comment: @Justin: reply is on its way.